# Redux, Firebase, and react-native: fetch data async

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

I'm developing a React-native app, using Redux and Firebase.
My Firebase database is denormalized, so it looks like:

```
users:
  user_uid:
    my_posts: [ post_key1, post_key2 ]

posts
  post_key1: { post_details }
  post_key2: { post_details }
```

How should I fetch data asynchronously and dispatch posts data to Redux store?

I know about Firebase methods .on('value') and .once('value'), but I'm not able to write a proper async function/thunk without generating issues.

Comment: any updates regarding this?

Comment: Are you using react-redux-firebase to integrate redux with firebase?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-redux-firebase` to integrate `redux` with `Firebase`, [the `v2.0.0` docs show](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/integrations/react-native.html) using react-native with examples for using either [native-modules through react-native-firebase](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/integrations/react-native.html#native-modules) or the [JS SDK](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/integrations/react-native.html#jsweb).

With the structure you have shown, it may also be helpful for you to use [`populate`](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/populate.html) to easily load posts automatically when loading users.

If you have the users `uid` on the post object under `owner`, you could do something like:

**Home.js**

```
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firebaseConnect, populate } from 'react-redux-firebase'

const populates = [
  { child: 'owner', root: 'users' } // replace owner with user object
]

const enhance = compose(
  firebaseConnect([
    // passing populates parameter also creates all necessary child queries
    { path: 'posts', populates }
  ]),
  connect(({ firebase }) => ({
    // populate original from data within separate paths redux
    posts: populate(firebase, 'posts', populates),
  }))
)

const SomeComponent = ({ posts }) => <div>{JSON.stringify(posts, null, 2)}</div>

export default enhance(SomeComponent)
```

**App.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { reactReduxFirebase, firebaseReducer } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import Home from './Home' // code above

const firebaseConfig = {} // config from firebase console

// react-redux-firebase config
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users' // automatically manage profile
}

// initialize firebase instance
firebase.initializeApp(config) // <- new to v2.*.*

// Add reduxReduxFirebase enhancer when making store creator
const createStoreWithFirebase = compose(
  reactReduxFirebase(firebase, rrfConfig)
)(createStore)

// Add Firebase to reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  firebase: firebaseStateReducer
})

// Create store with reducers and initial state
const initialState = {}
const store = createStoreWithFirebase(rootReducer, initialState)

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
   <Home />
  </Provider>
);
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```